# codeigniter how to load data from module to view and controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to load `$newdataa` from module class to my view. It shows an error on the controller class at  `$newdataa` line.

**This is module class**

```
$query=$this->db->get("pbinfo");

foreach($query->result() as $rows) 
{
       $newdataa = array(
                        'id' =>$rows->id,
                        'jtitle'  =>$rows->jtitle,
                        'skills' =>$rows->skills,
                        'email'         => $rows->email,
                        'country'    => $rows->country,
                        'rate'    => $rows->rate,
                        'website'   => $rows->website,
                        'phone'     => $rows->phone,
                        'aboutus' => $rows->aboutus,

                   );
               return true;    
         }
}
```

**This is controller class**

```
public function services()
{   
   $this->user_model->showfreelancer();
   $this->load->view("services",$newdataa);
}
```

Comment: So, what's the error message?

Comment: can you post the error messages you get and full controller class

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: newdataa

Filename: controllers/Pages.php

Line Number: 66

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 66
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your module:

```
return true;
```

to be:

```
return $this->db->select("pbinfo", $newdataa);
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: newdataa